# Como validar que solo se permita subir archivos XML

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Estoy realizando la subida de archivos al server con la ayuda de AJAX y PHP, pero en esta caso quiero que solo se me permita subir archivos XML.

Comparto a continuación el código JQuery y el llamado AJAX para la carga del archivo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#upload").on("click", function(){
        var ArchivoXml = $("#XmlToUpload").prop('files')[0];
        var datosForm = new FormData;

        datosForm.append("XmlToUpload", ArchivoXml);

        var filePath="server.php"
        console.log(ArchivoXml);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: datosForm,
            url:filePath
        }).done(function(data){
            alert(data)
        }).fail(function(){
            alert('El archivo no se pudo cargar')
        });

        //alert('Entro');    
    })
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Archivo XML:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" required>
              </div>
                    </div>
                    
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Adicional comparto mi código PHP **server.php** donde le asigno la ruta de guardado.

```
<?php
    //echo "hola mundo";
    if(isset($_FILES["XmlToUpload"])){
        $archivo = $_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["name"];
        $ruta ="XML/";

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$ruta.$archivo)){
            echo "Subido exitosamente";
        }else{
            echo "Error al subir";
        }
        //echo "SI LLEGO";
    }else {
        echo "No se selecciono un archivo";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Una comprobacion de ese tipo realmente es mucho mas dificil de lo que crees, pues enrealidad distintos tipos de archivos pueden ser disfrazados como `XML` y justamente ese es el problema, Este tipo de comprobaciones sin fallas de seguridad no es algo para nada facil de realizar ya que hay pocas formas de realizar bien esa comprobacion sin caer en fallas de seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

Hola mi hermano cómo estás.

Mi manera de hacerlo es utilizando la api de [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File) que traen los navegadores por defecto para de esa manera válidar el tipo de archivo.

Y también le pongo al input que sólo acept XML, aunque facilmente es burlable, por eso lo valido igualemente.

código:

```js
//Guardamos el input tipo file
/*const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('change', e => {
  //guardamos el archivo seleccionado con la API "FILE"
  const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];

  //si el arhcivo es diferente a xml
  if (file.type !== 'text/xml') {
    //reseteo el valor del input
    e.currentTarget.value = '';
    //muestro una alerta (estas alertas son feas,
    //ya tu las puedes cambiar por una librería o una alerta tuya)
    alert('Por favor seleccione un archivo XML');
    return;
  }

  console.log('Archivo válido');
  //procedes a enviar el archivo ya sea con axios, ajax, etc.....
}); */

// ACTUALIZACIÓN:
//si quieres aplicar esté código al que tu ya tenía debería de quedar
//algo cómo lo siguiente:

// OJO: ready está deprecado mi hermano
$(function () {
  $('#upload').on('click', function () {
    const ArchivoXml = $('#XmlToUpload').prop('files')[0];
    const datosForm = new FormData();
    
    if (ArchivoXml.type !== 'text/xml') {
      $('#XmlToUpload').val('');
      alert('Por favor seleccione un archivo XML');
      return;
    }

    datosForm.append('XmlToUpload', ArchivoXml);

    const filePath = 'server.php';
    
     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: datosForm,
      url: filePath,
    })
      .done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
      })
      .fail(function () {
        alert('El archivo no se pudo cargar');
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>Respuesta de stack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" accept="text/xml" id="XmlToUpload" />
    <button id="upload" >Upload</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Ya tu lo puedes adaptar cómo más gustes, ya sea con un framework, estilos de css o sass, alertas de una librería, etc.

Espero te halla ayudado, el código está explicado pero igual te dejo enlaces:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/log

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

### Edit:

Apliqué tu código con el mio para que no te enredes ;)

Comment: Tu respuesta parece funcionar para este caso, pero se me confuso con respecto al código que estoy utilizando en mi pregunta, con esto que comentas en tu respuesta debo reestructurar todo mi código o cambiar lo que he desarrollado hasta el momento ?  Hay manera de utilizar el código de tu respuesta con lo que tengo desarrollado ?

Comment: Muy buena tu respuesta te felicito Jesus, sin embargo debo aclarar que este codigo no servira para aquellos archivos que no tengan la extension en su nombre, por ejemplo un document xml llamado `documento`.

Comment: @Riven pues mi amigo, sería muy muy raro tener un xml sin extensión, ya eso es una exepción que tu cómo desarrollador no debes de preocuparte, casi nadie tendrá el archivo sin extensión, a menos que tu aplicación lo requiera

Comment: @JohnDoe, no tienes que hacer muchos cambios, igual dejame y edito la respuesta poniendo tu código ;)

Comment: @JesúsGarcía Ya con esta actualización a tu respuesta obtengo mucha mas claridad, solo una cosa adicional para no generar una pregunta con básicamente lo mismo, hay manera de agregar en la validación que permita archivos en formato PDF ?

Comment: @JohnDoe claro que sí, sólo sigue la misma lógica, en el if valida tanto XML como PDF

Comment: @JesúsGarcía Estaría bien usar algo como `if (ArchivoXml.type !== 'text/xml' || ArchivoPdf.type !== 'text/pdf' )` ?

Comment: @JohnDoe lo único que te faltaría sería quitar el `||` por un `&&`, y listo!

Comment: @JesúsGarcía Obtengo el siguiente error al hacerlo así como lo planteo `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

Comment: @JohnDoe eso significa que "ArchivoPdf" es indefinido, por lo tanto no puede sacar la propiedad de "type", ya eso no te lo puedo solucionar, tienes que mirar que estas haciendo mal, te recomiendo mandes todo a consola y lo analices